# How can I display an organized hierarchical data in asp.net 3.5?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, structure, organization

I am working on a project that organizes the structure and hierarchy of departments. I want to view and display the whole structure of the organization visually, but I am stuck. I wanted to know what is the best way to do it in ASP.net 3.5; my goal is to achieve something like [this](http://www.ocean.org.il/Eng/_images/pageImages/img_OrganizationStructure.gif) by code and each node is linkable and can have CSS.
The tree view won't fit neither master details grid view will fit to my requirements.

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an easier way and much flexible and doesnt require complex coding , i used MS Visio API i hope this answer helps others.

Regards
Mohammad Masoud

Answer (score 0):

They can all be on the same level physically. Logically, you could use JQuery to construct a tabbed menu system to separate the different levels:

http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2009/05/03/Beginning-JQuery-Cool-Menu-with-Master-Page.aspx

Comment: Thanks IrishChieftain 
What you suggested will not give me the visual effect i want as in the link i provided.

Comment: You can duplicate that structure in your sitemap xml - very simple :-)